# using dd to get certain parts of the sdcard - use bs and count?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

Now that I am running dd, I am worried that I might be getting the bs and the count wrong…
This is the command I used…

```
dd if=/dev/nbd1 conv=sync,noerror bs=4M count=3082239 | gzip -c  > /mnt/usbdrive/backup_image3.img.gz
```

But do I need bs if I am doing the count….
I want just these sectors:

```
partition1 2048-10239
partition2 10240-3082239
```

Comment: *"I am worried that I might be getting the bs and the count wrong"* -- Yes, you are wrong.  First, that's a strange device name.  Second, if you want to copy two partitions, then you need to use two commands, not just one.  Third, the `count` is for blocks of size `bs`, whereas the sectors that you refer to are of size 512 bytes.  BTW such a huge `bs=4M` probably has no benefit; the device cannot transfer that much data in one operation.

Comment: strange isn't always bad is it?  LOL   It is how my embedded device calls the sdcard and the on board emmc.
So, it appears, that due to how the memory is reference, i can't just blindly copy everything in giant chunks, and 4M would require a lower bs count, so, if I do the following, I have success and no input/output error. I get exactly what I want.

`dd if=/dev/nbd1 bs=512 count=3284491 | gzip -c  > /mnt/usbdrive/backup_image3`

Comment: You have to clarify what you what to do.  Are those sector numbers relative to each partition, or absolute to the start of the SDcard?  Typically `/dev/xxx1` would refer to the first partition of the device; to reference the entire device you would use `/dev/xxx` (no digit/ partition number).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, just had to think about it for a minute:  I had to find where my partition ended, using `fdisk /dev/nbd1` and just use the 512 default setting and put the ending number for that partition as my count.
See below:

`dd if=/dev/nbd1 bs=512 count=3284491 | gzip -c > /mnt/usbdrive/backup_image3`